# How to mention a formula idiomatically? a formula, a piece of formula, or something else?

Tags: word-usage

In another post ([singular or plural: "this kind of thing" or "this kind of things", when to use which?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238100/95044)), I referred to this bunch as grammar formulas

```
"Although" + subject + verb, subject + verb
"Even though" + subject + verb, subject + verb
```

and each one of those as *a formula*.

How to mention each one of those idiomatically? a formula, a piece of formula, or something else?

Comment: I think the words **pattern** or **construction** might work very well here.

Comment: So, '"Although" + subject + verb, subject + verb' is a pattern, and '"Even though" + subject + verb, subject + verb' is another pattern, right? sounds a little bit strange.

Comment: Yeah, **grammar pattern**. I would think it's a commonly used term in English grammar: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern Another link: http://grammarpatterns.com/ I think that **sentence structures** is yet another good term that might also work very well in your context.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Your link is quite helpful. Thank you. I got a sense that **two** of my formulas might be **one** pattern.

Comment: I would simply refer to both of them as **sentence structures**.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin What if I mention one piece of them?

Comment: Then jues say **a sentence structure**. What's the problem?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Okay, but later.